# How can I remove this commercial Schlage door latch?

Tags: doors, lock

I just moved into a new place and am trying to swap out the front door lock with a smart lock. It appears that the house (which was built in the 70s) came with some industrial locks and I can't seem to find a way to take them off.

Does anyone know what keywords I can use to find an instruction manual for the Schlage lock pictured below?
[image]

Comment: Say you get the locks off.  What then?  Do you actually have a mortise style smart lock to take its place?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Assa Abloy/Yale make mortise locks; some of them do support keyless entry with a pushbutton or capacitive touch keypad. To that module a radio module can be added for ZWave, ZigBee, BLE, (or other?) wireless technologies. Though there aren't many smart mortise lock options on the US market.. there are a few, at least.

Comment: @JPhi1618 thanks for giving me the name for the lock style. My eventual goal is to swap it out with a smart lock (or at least a keypad lock). But I wasn't sure what to put in Google to even see if that's an option with the current door. Now that I have a starting point, I can do a little more independent research!

Comment: Often those latchsets are sized uncommonly, and updating them is a pain ina residential environment. You can get commercial smart latches for them but if I were you I would look into th cost of replacing the door with one having a more common residential bore hole. That might make your other latch and keyset selections cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is a commercial-style *mortise latchset*; since we know it's a Schlage, a quick peek in their current catalog matches this to their L-series of latchsets.  These are fairly tough beasts on their own, tested to BHMA Grade 1 standards (and beyond) for commercial and institutional use (for instance: the high-rise office building I work in has them fitted everywhere panic/FE hardware isn't called for).

The bad news, unfortunately, is that Allegion/Schlage doesn't publish service manuals for older latchset designs on their website, just the [current build standard](https://us.allegion.com/content/dam/allegion-us-2/web-documents-2/Manual/Schlage_L_Series_Service_Manual_106500.pdf).  (The current L-series design dates back to 2001.)  So, you'll likely have to either contact them directly or get in touch with a local locksmith that's a Schlage Commercial dealer to get help, although you might still be able to find something useful in the current service manual all the same.

The good news, on the other hand, is that you *can* get a smartlock that's a straight replacement for this -- Schlage makes the LE variant of their L series that integrates RFID/NFC functionality with a standard mortise backup cylinder and runs on 4 AA batteries mounted on the inside of the door.  However, as you'd expect for something that's institutional-grade, it's not cheap by any means.  You could also use a lower-tech option such as a modern Simplex-style keypad lock as commercial mortise preps have been standardized for some time now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! This gives me a great head start on the project. I'm hoping there are some youtube videos that give me the basic understanding of how a Schlage latchset is installed for me to be able to reverse engineer this one.